# Adding context to a Class Based View (detail view) geting an error get_context_data() got an unexpected keyword argument 'object'

Tags: django, django-views

I am trying to learn how to add a 2nd Context to a Class-Based view which has always been an issue for me and I can't get it right from the first time.

In my current project, I am trying to add a comment section to item detail view.

I am currently getting an error of `get_context_data() got an unexpected keyword argument 'object'`
which is from the item detail view as I indicated and I don't know who to fix it

Here is the item model:

```
class Item(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

here is the comment model:

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    STATUS = (
        ('New', 'New'),
        ('True', 'True'),
        ('False', 'False'),
    )
    item = models.ForeignKey(Item, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="ItemComments")
    subject = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    comment = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=STATUS, default='New')
    create_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return '{} by {}'.format(self.subject, str(self.user.username))

class CommentForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Comment
        fields = ['subject', 'comment']
```

here is the view:

```
class ItemDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Item
    template_name = "product.html"

    def get_context_data(request, id):
        context = super(ItemDetailView, request).get_context_data() <---------------- error from this line
        context["comments"] = Comment.objects.filter(item_id=id, status='True')
        return context
```

here is the add coment view

```
def addcomment(request,id):
    url = request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER')  # get last url
    # return HttpResponse(url)
    if request.method == 'POST':  # check post
        form = CommentForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            data = Comment()  # create relation with model
            data.subject = form.cleaned_data['subject']
            data.comment = form.cleaned_data['comment']
            data.item_id = id
            current_user = request.user
            data.user_id = current_user.id
            data.save()  # save data to table
            messages.success(request, "Your review has ben sent. Thank you for your interest.")
            return HttpResponseRedirect(url)

    return HttpResponseRedirect(url)
```

Here is the traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Ahmed\Desktop\Project 4.3\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\Ahmed\Desktop\Project 4.3\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "C:\Users\Ahmed\Desktop\Project 4.3\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Ahmed\Desktop\Project 4.3\venv\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 71, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Ahmed\Desktop\Project 4.3\venv\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 97, in dispatch
    return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Ahmed\Desktop\Project 4.3\venv\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\detail.py", line 107, in get
    context = self.get_context_data(object=self.object)
  File "C:\Users\Ahmed\Desktop\Project 4.3\core\views.py", line 113, in get_context_data
    context["comments"] = Comment.objects.filter(item_id=id, status='True')
  File "C:\Users\Ahmed\Desktop\Project 4.3\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 82, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Ahmed\Desktop\Project 4.3\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 892, in filter
    return self._filter_or_exclude(False, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Ahmed\Desktop\Project 4.3\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 910, in _filter_or_exclude
    clone.query.add_q(Q(*args, **kwargs))
  File "C:\Users\Ahmed\Desktop\Project 4.3\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 1290, in add_q
    clause, _ = self._add_q(q_object, self.used_aliases)
  File "C:\Users\Ahmed\Desktop\Project 4.3\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 1315, in _add_q
    child_clause, needed_inner = self.build_filter(
  File "C:\Users\Ahmed\Desktop\Project 4.3\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 1251, in build_filter
    condition = self.build_lookup(lookups, col, value)
  File "C:\Users\Ahmed\Desktop\Project 4.3\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 1116, in build_lookup
    lookup = lookup_class(lhs, rhs)
  File "C:\Users\Ahmed\Desktop\Project 4.3\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\lookups.py", line 20, in __init__
    self.rhs = self.get_prep_lookup()
  File "C:\Users\Ahmed\Desktop\Project 4.3\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related_lookups.py", line 115, in get_prep_lookup
    self.rhs = target_field.get_prep_value(self.rhs)
  File "C:\Users\Ahmed\Desktop\Project 4.3\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 966, in get_prep_value
    return int(value)
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'builtin_function_or_method'
```

Comment: context = super(ItemDetailView,  self).get_context_data(**kwargs) instead of argument request it should be self

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The signature of **`get_context_data(...)`** method is wrong in your view. It should be as follows,

```
class ItemDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Item
    template_name = "product.html"

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context["comments"] = Comment.objects.filter(item=self.object, status='True')
        return context
```

Comment: Hi I applied your code but I am getting `int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'builtin_function_or_method'
`

Comment: I have fixed few typos. Double-check the code you have tried with *latest* one and do let me know

Comment: same error `int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'builtin_function_or_method'
`

Comment: add your complete error traceback to ***question***

Comment: I added the traceback

Comment: the traceback itself says you are not using the ***exact version of the answer that I have written here***

Comment: use **`item=self.object`** instead of `item_id=id`